# Remove special characters in ArtifactId Maven in Archetype Project

Tags: maven, maven-archetype, archetypes

I am using ${artifactId} to name some classes as well as **artifactId**, it works great unless someone puts in something with a - or a . and I'm sure other special symbols.  Is there any way to be able to strip these out?

Comment: Why do you do such thing? What is the purpose? And by which plugin?

Comment: It's a maven archetype project. When someone uses the archetype I want the ${artifactId} to name a file in my application, the problem is if you put - in the file name it will not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

create another property key for special classes name in archetype-metadata.xml.

```
<requiredProperties>
    <requiredProperty key="projectName">
        <defaultValue>hntest</defaultValue>
    </requiredProperty>
    <requiredProperty key="ConstantClassName">
        <defaultValue>HnTestConstant</defaultValue>
    </requiredProperty>
</requiredProperties>
```

${artifactId} normally use to name project in pom.xml,so u'd better not to mixed :)